# TensorFlow issue with tf.train.import_meta_graph - RuntimeError: The Session graph is empty. Add operations to the graph before calling run()

Tags: tensorflow, tornado

I am trying to improve the performance of our api which uses a model written in tensorflow. I have identified the line which is taking up to ten seconds to execute when multiple processes are executed.  It is:

```
saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(meta_path)
```

I am trying to cache this operation somehow and implemented the following code:

```
graph = None
```

In actual class:

```
global graph
if graph == None:
   print('init graph...')
   graph = tf.train.import_meta_graph(model_path)

saver = copy.deepcopy(graph)
```

This almost appears to work, but on the third request I get an error:

> **RuntimeError**: The Session graph is empty.  Add operations to the graph before calling run().

I am using tensorflow 1.5 and tornado 4.4.3. Updating these components is not possible.

Comment: if you have access to the model file, can you check if you're calling `tf.global_variables_initializer` before calling `tf.train.Saver()`

Comment: Yes it is calling tf.global_variables_initializer first.